# How to call a method with a parameter of type Class<out T> in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin

Being:

```
class Test {
    fun test(c: Class<out A>) {

    }
}

open class A

class B: A()
```

How is it possible to call `test` in `Test`with class `B` as argument?

Comment: `test.test(B::class.java)`

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```kotlin
val t = Test()
t.test(B::class.java)
```

`B::class` returns [`KClass<B>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/), then when you call `.java` it returns the java type i.e. [`Class<B>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) which is one of the type of `Class<out A>`.

[Test and play with the code yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/PouOB0Sbl).

Comment: This is what I thought. It compiles in IntelliJ but it gives an error:

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Test.test(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
 at PlayKt.main(Play.kt:3)
 at PlayKt.main(Play.kt)

Comment: @Pierre Thibault can you share the code in the question as well, it works flawlessly check the above snippet at well.

Comment: It works flawlessly. I had another class Test in another file that was causing problem. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

you could test this code for use your generic class:

```
fun <T : A> test(c: T) {

}
```

and then create the class for passing that in the parameters:

```
val b = B()
test(b)
```